# Any way to *list*, not remove, duplicate frames in an an MP4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I can use `ffmpeg -mpdecimate` to *remove* duplicate frames in a video file, but is there any way to just *list* them, using ffmpeg or otherwise?

Ideally I'd get an output saying nothing happens at time x for y frames.

Comment: Look at freezedetect filter.